# Specify size and maxlength for Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Server Side Validation On ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI. On a view(used to create) for a text field like this:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyTypeName).Name("CompanyTypeName")
```

I need to change the size of textbox. I tried like this:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyTypeName, new { style = "width:50px", @maxlength = "5" }).Name("CompanyTypeName")
```

But doesn't work.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is only valid using a default textbox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyTypeName, new { style = "width:50px", @maxlength = "5" })
```

This is what you can do:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyTypeName).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50px", @maxlength = "5" }).Name("CompanyTypeName")
```

Comment: the @ on @maxlength is important. I forgot to include it, and the length limitation was completely ignored.

Comment: it shouldn't be required.  The @ tells razor to escape from matching c expressions.  So if you wanted to add html attribute class you would have to have it, but maxlength shouldn't need it.